# Subclassin button WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing

In my project i have created a simple Button class:
button.hpp:

```
class Button : public Control {
    std::string text;
    int         id;

    std::function<void(void)>&& callback{};

    static inline const char* sClassName = "Button";
    static LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonSubclassProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR);
public:
    Button(HWND parent, POINT position, SIZE size, int id, const std::string& text) noexcept;
    virtual ~Button() noexcept;

    inline void SetCallback(std::function<void(void)>&& callback) noexcept { this->callback = callback; }
    NODISCARD inline int GetId() const noexcept { return id; }
private:
    NODISCARD bool CreateControl(HWND) noexcept override;
    void DestroyControl() noexcept override;
    void Invoke() const noexcept;
};
```

button.cpp:

```
#include "button.hpp"

Button::Button(HWND parent, POINT position, SIZE size, int id, const std::string& text) noexcept
    : Control(position, size), id(id), text(text) {

    isCreated = CreateControl(parent);
    SetWindowSubclass(hwnd, &Button::ButtonSubclassProc, id, reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(this));
}

Button::~Button() noexcept {
    RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, &Button::ButtonSubclassProc, id);
    DestroyControl();
}

NODISCARD bool Button::CreateControl(HWND parent) noexcept {
    hwnd = CreateWindow(sClassName, text.c_str(), WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, position.x, position.y, size.cx, size.cy, parent, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(id), reinterpret_cast<HINSTANCE>(GetWindowLong(parent, GWL_HINSTANCE)), NULL);
    return hwnd != NULL;
}

void Button::DestroyControl() noexcept {
    Control::DestroyControl();
}

void Button::Invoke() const noexcept {
    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK Button::ButtonSubclassProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR id, DWORD_PTR refData) {

    auto button = reinterpret_cast<Button*>(refData);
    if (uMsg == WM_COMMAND) {
        MessageBox(0, std::to_string(id).c_str(), 0, 0);

        button->Invoke();
        return TRUE;
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

that's how i pass message from main window procedure:

```
case WM_COMMAND: {
    return SendMessage(reinterpret_cast<HWND>(lParam), WM_COMMAND, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And it works fine when only one button is created, but when i try to create more, it does not matter which button i would push, i always get callback of the last created button.
I suppose this happens because of SetWindowSubclass call in counstructor and passing it `this` pointer, but i do not know what should i do. Read about GetWindowSubclass but i dont clearly understand how to use it.

Buttons are created in main window class:
mainwnd.hpp

```
class MainWindow : public NonCopyable, public NonMovable {
    HINSTANCE   handle;
    HWND        hwnd;
    int         width;
    int         height;

    bool isRegistered{ false };
    bool isCreated{ false };

    IRenderer* renderer;
    Button* buttonStart;
    Button* buttonStop;
    static inline const char* sClassName = "MAIN_WINDOW_CLASS";
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
public:
    explicit MainWindow(HINSTANCE handle, int width, int height) noexcept;
    ~MainWindow() noexcept;

    NODISCARD inline bool IsRegistered() const noexcept { return isRegistered; }
    NODISCARD inline bool IsCreated()    const noexcept { return isCreated; }

    NODISCARD bool CheckControls() const noexcept;

    NODISCARD inline int Width()  const noexcept { return width; }
    NODISCARD inline int Height() const noexcept { return height; }

    void Update() noexcept;
private:
    NODISCARD bool RegisterMainClass() const noexcept;
    NODISCARD bool CreateMainWindow() noexcept;

    void UnregisterMainClass() noexcept;
    void DestroyMainWindow() noexcept;

    void CreateControls() noexcept;
    void DestroyControls() noexcept;

    void OnButtonStartPushed();
    void OnButtonStopPushed();
};
```

mainwnd.cpp

```
#include "main_window.hpp"

MainWindow::MainWindow(HINSTANCE handle, int width, int height) noexcept 
    : width(width), height(height), handle(handle) {

    isRegistered = RegisterMainClass();
    isCreated    = CreateMainWindow();

    CreateControls();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() noexcept {
    DestroyControls();

    DestroyMainWindow();
    UnregisterMainClass();
}

bool MainWindow::RegisterMainClass() const noexcept {
    WNDCLASS wc;
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(WNDCLASSA));

    if (!GetClassInfo(handle, sClassName, &wc)) {
        wc.style         = 0;
        wc.hInstance     = handle;
        wc.lpszClassName = sClassName;
        wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;

        wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
        wc.cbWndExtra    = sizeof(LONG_PTR);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);

        wc.hIcon         = NULL;
        wc.hCursor       = NULL;
        wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    }

    return RegisterClass(&wc) != 0;
}

bool MainWindow::CreateMainWindow() noexcept {
    if (IsRegistered()) {
        hwnd = CreateWindow(sClassName, NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, width, height, NULL, NULL, handle, this);
    }
    return hwnd != NULL;
}

void MainWindow::UnregisterMainClass() noexcept {
    UnregisterClass(sClassName, handle);
    isRegistered = false;
}

void MainWindow::DestroyMainWindow() noexcept {
    if (hwnd) {
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        hwnd = NULL;
    }

    isCreated = false;
}

void MainWindow::CreateControls() noexcept {
    this->renderer = new Canvas(hwnd, { 10,10 }, { 200,200 });
    buttonStart = new Button(hwnd, { 300,50 }, { 100,40 }, 145, "Start");
    buttonStart->SetCallback(std::bind(&MainWindow::OnButtonStartPushed, this));

    buttonStop = new Button(hwnd, { 300,150 }, { 100,40 }, 168, "Stop");
    buttonStop->SetCallback(std::bind(&MainWindow::OnButtonStopPushed, this));
}

void MainWindow::DestroyControls() noexcept {
    delete renderer;
    delete buttonStart;
    delete buttonStop;
}

bool MainWindow::CheckControls() const noexcept {

    return renderer != 0;
}

void MainWindow::Update() noexcept {
    renderer->Redraw();
}

void MainWindow::OnButtonStartPushed() {
    MessageBox(0, "Start", 0, 0);
}

void MainWindow::OnButtonStopPushed() {
    MessageBox(0, "Stop", 0, 0);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindow::WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE) {
        MainWindow* window = reinterpret_cast<MainWindow*>(lParam);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(window));
        return TRUE;
    }

    auto window = reinterpret_cast<MainWindow*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA));
    if (window == nullptr) { 
        return FALSE; 
    }

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_DESTROY: {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND: {
        return SendMessage(reinterpret_cast<HWND>(lParam), WM_COMMAND, wParam, lParam);
    }

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Message Loop:

```
MSG message;
memset(&message, 0, sizeof(MSG));

while (true) {
    if (PeekMessage(&message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) != 0) {
        if (message.message == WM_QUIT) {
            break;
        }

        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    } else {
        mainWindow.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't see what's wrong with the code presented here. The bug could be in the base class or some other code that you are not showing. Need [mcve].

Comment: There is no enough info here. No where do you show how you are creating a button. Do they have the same IDs? etc..

Comment: @zett42 added main window class code

Comment: On a side note, you should move `RemoveWindowSubclass()` into `ButtonSubclassProc()` when processing `WM_NCDESTROY`. See [Safer subclassing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883). Your `DestroyControl()` is not the only way your HWND may be destroyed.

Comment: Why is your `Button::callback` member declared as an rvalue reference? It should not be a reference at all. Get rid of `&&` in the member declaration, as well as in the parameter of `SetCallback()`

Comment: Hi Anton, you can write a solution, and mark it as an answer, so that other community members can benefit from the thread:)